# Mysql/mariadb innodb: does row size affect complex query performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, mariadb, query-performance

I have InnoDB table with millions rows (statistics events) on my MariaDB 10 server and each row historically has a long user-id char(44) field (used as non-unique key) along with other 30 int/varchar fields (row size is about 240 bytes). My system can make cohort analysis, funnels, event segmentation and other common statistics - so some queries are very complex with many joins. Now I have an opportunity to add 4-byte int field and use it as user-id and as main non-unique key for all queries. But I need to keep old symbolic char(44) user-id in this table because of realization details - some data sources are not mine and send events only with symbolic user-ids.

So the question is: will - in general - keeping or removing this char(44) field affect performance of complex queries? It will just stay like other char fields, and it will not be used as a key in queries anymore. I'd prefer not to split the table because there are lot of code depend on its structure.

Thanks!

---

Tested Aria, and found out that it is ~1.5x slower than InnoDB for my purposes, even on simple joins. InnoDB with "redundant" row format works even faster. So - no, Aria is not a compromise, it is even slower than myISAM. I suppose InnoDB is XtraDB in Maria10, this explains the speed.

Also did some testing on self join query and found that leaving or removing char(44) field has no affect on query performance if we're not using this field.

And moving from char(44) key to int makes queries 2x faster!

Comment: `CHAR(44) utf8` takes 132 bytes always!  `INT` takes only 4.  Bigger --> takes more space --> fewer records per block --> more I/O --> slower.

Comment: @RickJames when I don't extract it in query it doesn't affect, but yes, its redundant field. yet currently I can't get rid of it because of third-party logic. Btw why it's 132 bytes? it is latin1_bin

Comment: Always 44 bytes in your case.  (Most people today use utf8.)

Answer (score 1):

Switching to a shorter integer key will help query performance a little bit.  The indexing overhead of fixed length character columns isn't hideous.

Stuffing more RAM and/or some SSD disks into your database server will most likely cost less than refactoring your program, as you have mentioned.

What will *really* help your query performance is the creation of appropriate [compound](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [covering indexes](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727). If you have queries that can be satisfied just from such an index, things will get faster.

For example, if you do a lot of

```
SELECT integer_user_id
  FROM table
 WHERE character_user_id = 'constant'
```

then a compound index on `(character_user_id)` will make this query very fast.

Be careful when you add lots of indexes: there's a penalty to pay upon INSERT or UPDATE in tables with many indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Of course I use SSD, 8 cores, 32G RAM, many simple and compound indexes for different queries, and insert time is not critical. But I've asked - can I leave old index column in the table? Will keeping it in or removing it from the table affect performance if I never use it in queries anymore?

Comment: You have plenty of hardware.  There is no need to eliminate the old 44-character column. Leave it in place.  (If it were a 128MiB TEXT column, the answer would be different!) If you have stopped using that column for queries, you can drop it from your indexes.

Comment: Thanks! Even such a big device works not so fast sometimes - millions of events of 100k+ users (free apps) in segmented funnels and complex cohorts analysis - are really heavy queries that take minutes to execute and to parse result datasets. Regarding to 44-char column - I'd prefer to keep it because I will need it in future, as symbolic uids are used by remote third-party systems, and I need an ability to point to some users later.

Comment: For what it's worth, PostgreSQL has superior statistical analysis / aggregate functions, as well as windowing operations.  The price is the same.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I worked with postgre about 8 years ago and almost forgot everything, and mysql I use very often in lightweight processing. now I regret started this project with mysql, but there are lot of code written, and of course there is no time to port now

Comment: by the way mariadb10 much faster than original mysql, and has lot of optimizations and improvements. so I chose it as compromise

Comment: Mariadb is definitely a good choice. The aria storage engine is a good compromise between the speed of MyISAM and the transactional stuff in InnoDb.